# is there a general rule related to "not" being incompatible with phrases like "There are clouds"?

Tags: negation

The adverb "not" can negate a lot of expressions in a straightforward way. We can put it after a helper verb, after forms of "be" if it happens not to be a helper verb, and we can add a helper verb "do" if needed. For example:

- I was reading the paper. I was *not* reading the paper. (not can follow a helper verb)
- I am a student. I am *not* a student. (not can follow "be", even if its not a helper verb)
- I read the paper. I do *not* read the paper. (we can add a helper verb "do" if needed to make a place to put not)
- It is cloudy. It is *not* cloudy. (another example of "not" following "be", related to the later counter-example)
- If there is a cloud in sight, it could rain. If there is *not* a cloud in sight, it could rain. (another example of "not" following "be", related to the later counter-example)

But then I find I cannot use "not" as such with expressions like "There are clouds."

- There are clouds. (incorrect after "be":) There are *not* clouds. (also incorrect to add do:)  There do *not* be clouds.

What just happened? Sure I could negate the sentence by saying "There are no clouds", or "There are not any clouds". But why do I need to do something different to negate this type of sentence? Is there a specific topic I could read about to understand this scenario more?

Comment: An observation: "There aren't clouds" seems more natural than "There are not clouds" (although "there aren't any clouds" is better). I guess this is due to what is usual/idiomatic.

Comment: The correct term is _auxiliary verb_, and _be_ is always an auxiliary verb. The usual position for _not_ (or any adverb) is following the first auxiliary verb in the verb phrase. You can say _There are not clouds_ to deny an assertion that there are. But aside from that context, what could it mean? There are no clouds anywhere? Clouds do not exist? There are currently no clouds outside? That's a very specific deictic meaning and one needs more than _not_ to get the specificity. [Negation](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) is a very complex subject.

Comment: I don't think "There are not clouds" is something someone can say as correct English. I think you may be saying its semantically incomplete, so we can accept it grammatically while still never using it. But in Spanish one can say "No hay nubes" and it simply means there are no clouds, without concern for semantic incompleteness.

Comment: Well, put another way, I think your concern about the incomplete meaning of "There are not clouds" would apply just as much to "There are no clouds".  But "There are no clouds" does not seem incorrect on its own in the same way as "There are not clouds."

Answer (score 2):

John Lawler commented:

> The correct term is *auxiliary verb*, and *be* is always an auxiliary verb. The usual position for *not* (or any adverb) is following the first auxiliary verb in the verb phrase. You can say *There are not clouds* to deny an assertion that there are.
>
> But aside from that context, what could it mean? There are no clouds anywhere? Clouds do not exist? There are currently no clouds outside? That's a very specific deictic meaning and one needs more than *not* to get the specificity. [Negation](http://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) is a very complex subject.